# Django printing dynamic field in template

Tags: django, django-templates

With a given model:

```
class Ventas(models.Model):
    producto = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="", blank=True, null=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField(help_text="Tier", blank=True, null=True)
    marca = models.ForeignKey(Marcas, help_text="Usuario", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categoria = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.producto )
```

I annotate a queryset using a dynamicaly chosen field as follows:

```
ventas_producto = ventas.values(ver_por_choices).annotate(
        uds_totales=F("uds_totales"),
        share=F("uds_totales"),
        ).order_by('-uds_totales')
```

The var "ver_por_choices" can take values of the fields of the model: `producto`, `stock`, `marca` or `categoria`

Then in the template I want to print the values as

```
{% for venta in ventas_producto %}
    <div>{{ venta.uds_totales}}</div>
    <div>{{ venta.share}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I print the dynamic field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not include it in the queryset as key:

```
ver_por_choices = 'Some field name'

ventas_producto = ventas.values(ver_por_choices).annotate(
    uds_totales=F('uds_totales'),
    share=F('uds_totales'),
    key=F(ver_por_choices)
).order_by('-uds_totales')
```

or even more convenient:

```
ventas_producto = ventas.values(
    uds_totales=F('uds_totales'),
    share=F('uds_totales'),
    key=F(ver_por_choices)
).order_by('-uds_totales')
```

Then you can usse this in the `{% for … %}` loop with:

```
{% for venta in ventas_producto %}
    <div>{{ venta.key }}</div>
    <div>{{ venta.uds_totales}}</div>
    <div>{{ venta.share}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I don't want to print the "ver_por_choices" value, I want to print the value of the field with the "ver_por_choices" vale as a name.

Comment: @FranciscoGhelfi: yes, since we wrap it in an `F`, key will use that value, so `{{ venta.key }}`, will take the value of the field with the name in `ver_por_choices`.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thanks